# Selecting values from dataframe based on multiple column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, preprocessor

I have a dataframe in this format:

|  | ageClass | sex | nationality | treatment | unique_id | netTime | clockTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 20 | M | KEN | Treatment | 354658649da56c20c72b6689d2b7e1b8cc334ac9 | 7661 | 7661 |
| 1 | 20 | M | KEN | Treatment | 1da607e762ac07eba6f9b5a717e9ff196d987242 | 7737 | 7737 |
| 2 | 20 | M | KEN | Control | 1de4a95cef28c290ba5790217288f510afc3b26b | 7747 | 7747 |
| 3 | 30 | M | KEN | Control | 12215d93d2cb5b0234991a64d097955338a73dd3 | 7750 | 7750 |
| 4 | 30 | M | KEN | Treatment | 5375986567be20b49067956e989884908fb807f6 | 8163 | 8163 |
| 5 | 20 | M | ETH | Treatment | 613be609b3f4a38834c2bc35bffbdb6c47418666 | 7811 | 7811 |
| 6 | 20 | M | KEN | Control | 70fb3284d112dc27a5cad7f705b38bc91f56ecad | 7853 | 7853 |
| 7 | 30 | M | AUS | Control | 0ea5d606a83eb68c89da0a98543b815e383835e3 | 7902 | 7902 |
| 8 | 20 | M | BRA | Control | ecdd57df778ad901b41e79dd2713a23cb8f13860 | 7923 | 7923 |
| 9 | 20 | M | ETH | Control | ae7fe893268d86b7a1bdb4489f9a0798797c718c | 7927 | 7927 |

The objective is to determine which age class benefitted most from being in the treatment group as measured by clocktime.
That means i need to somehow group all values for members in each agegroup for both treatment and control conditions and take an average of their clocktimes.
Then following that i need to take  the difference of the average clocktimes for the subgroups and  compare all of these against one another.

Where i am stuck is with filtering the dataframe based on multiple columns simulatneously. I tried using groupby() as follows:

```
df.groupby(['ageClass','treatment'])['clockTime'].mean()
```

However I was not able to then calculate the difference in the mean times from the resulting series.

How should I move forward?

Answer (score 2):

You can pivot the table with means you produced

```
df2 = df.groupby(['ageClass','treatment'])[['clockTime']].mean().reset_index().pivot(columns=['ageClass'], values='clockTime', index='treatment')

ageClass    20  30
treatment       
Control     7862.500000     7826.0
Treatment   7736.333333     8163.0
```

Then it's easy to find a difference

```
df2['diff'] = df2[20] - df2[30]

treatment
Control       36.500000
Treatment   -426.666667
Name: diff, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 2):

From the `groupby` you've already done, you can `groupby` index level 0, i.e. `'ageClass'` and then use `diff` to find the difference between the averages of treatment and control groups for each `'ageClass'`. Since `diff` subtracts the second from the first (and "Control" and "Treatment" are sorted alphabetically), add `"-Control"` to make it a bit clearer.

```
s = df.groupby(['ageClass','treatment'])['clockTime'].mean()
out = s.groupby(level=0).diff().dropna().reset_index()
out = out.assign(treatment=out['treatment']+'-Control')
```

Output:

```
   ageClass          treatment   clockTime
0        20  Treatment-Control -126.166667
1        30  Treatment-Control  337.000000
```

Answer (score 1):

From your problem description, I would prescribe ranking. Differences between groups wont tell who benefited the most

```
s=df.groupby(['ageClass','treatment'])['clockTime'].agg('mean').reset_index()

s['rank']=s.groupby('ageClass')['clockTime'].rank()



    ageClass  treatment    clockTime  rank
0        20    Control  7862.500000   2.0
1        20  Treatment  7736.333333   1.0
2        30    Control  7826.000000   1.0
3        30  Treatment  8163.000000   2.0
```